# How can I obtain the method name executed for a piece of software that I don't own the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We have a CRM software and we're allowed to build a plugin for it. There's a specific button action in the main software that I would like to call from my plugin.

Is there a way in Visual Studio to watch what is happening when I click on that button even thought the software is compiled ?

Thank you !

Comment: You may be able to use ILspy to simply look at the code, assuming it wasn't scrambled.

Comment: I was hoping something like : Open visual studio -> Start the application from visual studio using a certain mode (which I'm looking for) -> In the application, go where the button is, go back to VS and click "watch" -> go back to the application and click the button to obtain the method name that is executed.

Answer (score 3):

If the compiled code is not obfuscated, you can view entire assembly using [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) or [JetBrains dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). The first one is commercial software. The second one is free.

Don't know a lot about `.NET Reflector` but with `dotPeek` extension for `Visual Studio` you can view the code of entire class or single method using `F12` hotkey while pointing caret at class or method respectively. The option can be also accessed from the context menu and is called 'Go to declaration' or 'Go to implementation'.

Comment: Note that your license agreement for the CRM may or may not allow this.

Comment: Of course. Decompilation of software may be considered as a violation of the license. You should be careful with that.

Comment: The company who made this software went down. Phone is disconnected, domain not renewed, owner now working for someone instead of being a company owner and more magically they stopped billing us our annual licence fee 3 years ago. They made us an API for their software for us to build our plugin around their software.

Answer (score 0):

If your CRM software is a .NET application, you can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to see what is happening when you click on that button.